# S3 bucket existence using HEAD bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am using an App where I store some artifacts in an S3 bucket. I want to check that the bucket exists before I push the artifacts. I referred the S3 API reference and the the method 'doesBucketExist' seems to only check for the existence of the bucket and does not actually verify that its in the same account as the request.

Reference: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#doesBucketExist-java.lang.String-

I wanted to know if the headBucket method is effective to verify if the bucket exists and is in the same account as the request? Or is there a better way to verify the existence of the bucket in an account?

Thanks

Comment: Can't you just try to create a small file?

Comment: I would suggest that you're wasting time trying to discover this.  It is for all practical purposes impossible to determine conclusively whether uploading a *specific* object to a bucket will succeed... other than by trying to upload the object.  Bucket policies and IAM user policies allow granular access control to the point that you might -- for any one bucket -- be able to create an object named `foo` but not an object named `bar`.  When a test has so many ways to false positive or negative, it is not a valuable test.

Comment: By way of example, many of my buckets will deny an upload that doesn't specify the correct `x-amz-server-side-encryption` value.  The user, by all evidence, has full access to the bucket... yet if they try an unencrypted upload, `AccessDenied`.

Answer (score 0):

`head-bucket` is often used to check if the bucket exists before creating it, it does not reveal the account that owns the bucket. To know the exact account owner, your user would need to have the `s3:GetBucketAcl` permission and then use `get-bucket-acl` API that would give you the complete ownership information for the bucket.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/get-bucket-acl.html

Comment: I am not sure how well the display name can be validated for permissions and the cannonical user ID seems to be something which we can't really provide as an input upfront to verify?

Comment: You could use list-buckets to get a list of buckets owned by the user of the request, and then check if that particular bucket is in the list.

Comment: This doc from S3's API reference says that head bucket is used to determine if the bucket is in the account and you have access to it - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#headBucket-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.HeadBucketRequest. Do you think this isn't the best way to evaluate?

Comment: Yes, it will tell you if you have permission to access it, but it does not confirm the ownership of the bucket. The bucket could also be a public bucket, where any user can access it. If you care only about permissions, rather than ownership, then you can use head-bucket.